# BrowserSync reload doesn't work (wordpress site)

Tags: node.js, wordpress, gulp, browser-sync

I'm having problems getting the live reload to work in BrowserSync. I have a wordpress site if it makes any difference. Everything but the live reload/injecting seems to work as it should. I have a Gulp setup for this that looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
    var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
    var concat = require('gulp-concat');
    var rename = require('gulp-rename');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
    var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
    var del = require('del');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
    var reload = browserSync.reload;

// ==== CONFIGURATION ==== //
// Project paths
var src         = 'assets/',
    dist        = 'dist/',
    bower       = src + 'bower_components/',
    css         = dist + 'css/',
    js          = dist + 'js/'
;


// Lint and minify our Javascript files
gulp.task('js-linting-compiling', ['clean'], function(){

    // read all of the files that are in script/lib with a .js extension
    return gulp.src('assets/js/*.js')
        // run their contents through jshint
        .pipe(jshint())
        // report any findings from jshint
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        // concatenate all of the file contents into a file titled 'all.js'
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        // write that file to the dist/js directory
        .pipe(gulp.dest(js))
        // now rename the file in memory to 'all.min.js'
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        // run uglify (for minification) on 'all.min.js'
        .pipe(uglify())
        // write all.min.js to the dist/js file
        .pipe(gulp.dest(js));
});


// Compile SASS into CSS, autoprefix it and minify it
gulp.task('sass-to-css', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.src('assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(css))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '_min' }))
        .pipe(minifyCSS({keepSpecialComments:0}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(css))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});


// Clean our dist folder before we generate new content into it
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
  del([
    // here we use a globbing pattern to match everything inside the `dist` folder
    'dist/**',
  ], cb);
});


// ### Build
// `gulp build` - Run all the build tasks but don't clean up beforehand.
// Generally you should be running `gulp` instead of `gulp build`.
gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'sass-to-css', 'js-linting-compiling'], function() {
});


// ### Gulp
// `gulp` - Run a complete build. To compile for production run `gulp --production`.
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
  gulp.start('build');
});


// ### Watch
// `gulp watch` - Use BrowserSync to proxy your dev server and synchronize code
// changes across devices. Specify the hostname of your dev server at
// `manifest.config.devUrl`. When a modification is made to an asset, run the
// build step for that asset and inject the changes into the page.
// See: http://www.browsersync.io
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  browserSync({
    proxy: "local.project.dev",
    host: "localhost",
    notify: false,
  });
  gulp.watch(['assets/sass/**/*'], ['sass-to-css']);
  gulp.watch(['assets/js/**/*'], ['js-linting-compiling']);
  gulp.watch('**/*.php', function() {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
});
```

This is what the terminal shows when updating a *.scss file (running gulp watch).

```
[13] → gulp watch
[11:39:17] Using gulpfile ~/sites/VVV/www/local.project.dev/htdocs/app/themes/mytheme/gulpfile.js
[11:39:17] Starting 'watch'...
[11:39:19] Finished 'watch' after 1.4 s
[BS] Proxying: http://local.project.dev
[BS] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.111:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.111:3001
 --------------------------------------
[11:40:10] Starting 'clean'...
[11:40:10] Finished 'clean' after 6.12 ms
[11:40:10] Starting 'sass-to-css'...
[11:40:10] Finished 'sass-to-css' after 6.54 ms
[BS] 1 file changed (style_min.css)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What url are you looking at?

Comment: Running the gulp watch command automatically opens my wordpress project at: http://localhost:3000/

So my custom domain name does not show up, even though the page works as it should at that adress too. Is this not expected behavior or should BrowserSync work with my custom adress?

Comment: Live reload should work in that opened address.

Comment: Should I see some indication of this in the terminal?

Comment: No, but if you enable `notify` you'll see notification in the browser.

Comment: Are you using minified or non-minified css files in your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling browser-sync to reload only your minified css version. You probably use non-minified version in your page and that causes the problem.

So either reload just non-minified:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(css))
.pipe(reload({stream: true}))
.pipe(rename({ suffix: '_min' }))
.pipe(minifyCSS({keepSpecialComments:0}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(css));
```

or both:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(css))
.pipe(reload({stream: true}))
.pipe(rename({ suffix: '_min' }))
.pipe(minifyCSS({keepSpecialComments:0}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(css))
.pipe(reload({stream: true}));
```

.. or use minified version in page.